# LinkageError after upgrading dropwizard to 0.8.1

Tags: java, gradle, dropwizard

I've upgraded dropwizard from 0.7.1 to 0.8.1 and keep getting this exception:

```
Error:Groovyc: A groovyc error occurred while trying to load one of the classes in project dependencies, please ensure it's present. See the message and the stack trace below for reference
java.lang.LinkageError: ClassCastException: attempting to castjar:file:/home/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.ws.rs/jsr311-api/1.1.1/59033da2a1afd56af1ac576750a8d0b1830d59e6/jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar!/javax/ws/rs/ext/RuntimeDelegate.classtojar:file:/home/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.ws.rs/jsr311-api/1.1.1/59033da2a1afd56af1ac576750a8d0b1830d59e6/jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar!/javax/ws/rs/ext/RuntimeDelegate.class
    at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.findDelegate(RuntimeDelegate.java:116)
    at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.getInstance(RuntimeDelegate.java:91)
    at javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.<clinit>(MediaType.java:44)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.newFieldAccessor(UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newFieldAccessor(ReflectionFactory.java:142)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.acquireFieldAccessor(Field.java:1088)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.getFieldAccessor(Field.java:1069)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:393)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AnnotationVisitor.transformInlineConstants(AnnotationVisitor.java:131)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AnnotationVisitor.visit(AnnotationVisitor.java:76)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.ExtendedVerifier.visitAnnotation(ExtendedVerifier.java:246)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.ExtendedVerifier.visitAnnotations(ExtendedVerifier.java:137)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.ExtendedVerifier.visitClass(ExtendedVerifier.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$16.call(CompilationUnit.java:789)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1052)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:588)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:543)
    at org.jetbrains.groovy.compiler.rt.GroovyCompilerWrapper.compile(GroovyCompilerWrapper.java:54)
    at org.jetbrains.groovy.compiler.rt.DependentGroovycRunner.runGroovyc(DependentGroovycRunner.java:87)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.jetbrains.groovy.compiler.rt.GroovycRunner.main(GroovycRunner.java:100)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:130)
```

I have two RuntimeDelegate instances in: jersey-core-1.18.3.jar & jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar.

Did anyone encouter this?

Comment: not sure what RuntimeDelegate instances are but you shouldn't have anything with jersey 1.x with dropwizard 0,8.x since it's jersey 2 based.

Comment: dropwizard 0.8.1 has Jersey 2.17

Comment: RuntimeDelegate is an abstract class that loads the RuntimeDelegate implementation using the thread context class loader if present, or the system class loader if not.  The Linkage error is occurring because you have two RuntimeDelegate classes, loaded from different class loaders. This typically happens when the RuntimeDelegate.getInstance() method from the second class loader uses the RuntimeDelegate implementation from the system class loader